# Jquery: bxsider controls are not properly load

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, bxslider

In bxslider , controls are always bottom of slides. And it isn't render bx-controls div.
I am using bxslider in sharepoint 2013 master page. 
Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the controls elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the controls to anywhere but the default you might want to consider using the pagerCustom callback see [BXSlider's Custom Pager Example](http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1)

With this method you can put the pager anywhere you like. Just make sure you use the correct ID on whatever object you use as the pager.